# Where does the try/except statement go when calling a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, try-except

I have my main Python script where I am calling a function.  I want to catch any errors that happen during the execution of the function and if there are any errors I want to set the error variable to true.  Is the try/except statement done in the main script like so:

```
try:
  image_convert(filepath,'.jpg','RGB',2500,2500)

except:
  error = true
```

Or is it done inside the function like this:

```
def image_convert(filepath,imageType,colorMode,height,width):
   try:
    imwrite(filepath[:-4] + imageType, imread(filepath)[:,:,:3].copy()) # <-- using the imagecodecs library function of imread, make a copy in memory of the TIFF File.
    # The :3 on the end of the numpy array is stripping the alpha channel from the TIFF file if it has one so it can be easily converted to a JPEG file.
    # Once the copy is made the imwrite function is creating a JPEG file from the TIFF file.
    # The [:-4] is stripping off the .tif extension from the file and the + '.jpg' is adding the .jpg extension to the newly created JPEG file.
    img = Image.open(filepath[:-4] + imageType) # <-- Using the Image.open function from the Pillow library, we are getting the newly created JPEG file and opening it.
    img = img.convert(colorMode) # <-- Using the convert function we are making sure to convert the JPEG file to RGB color mode.
    imageResize = img.resize((height, width)) # <-- Using the resize function we are resizing the JPEG to 2500 x 2500
    imageResize.save(filepath[:-4] + imageType) # <-- Using the save function, we are saving the newly sized JPEG file over the original JPEG file initially created.
    return(imageResize)
  except:
     error = true
```

Comment: The second version won't be much use unless you make the `error` variable somehow accessible to the calling context.

Comment: I wouldn't catch the error in the function. If you do, your function is worrying about handling errors along with its actual task. If it throws, it throws. Whoever wants to deal with the error can catch it. Sometimes it's appropriate, but I don't see any reason here why the function should know anything about `error`.

Comment: Could be a combination of *both*, depending on what exceptions *could* be raised. Some of them you may be able to deal with in some way inside the function, others may be better to propagate to give someone else a chance to handle them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first method will work

```
try:
    image_convert(filepath,'.jpg','RGB',2500,2500)
except:
    error = true
```

Answer (score 0):

As the function call is made from inside a try block, any errors/exceptions during the execution of the function code will also come under the area of the try block and hence will be redirected to the except block.

a simple example to this may be as below:

```
def test():
    raise Exception 

try:
    test()

except:
    error = True
    print(error)
```

the output will be :

True